# jQuery Resize - having problems

Tags: jquery, html, css, drag

If you look at my site [here](http://www.ewsprojects.com/~lyons/new.php), when you try to post a tag (button on right), you can move it around and everything and the info part (with the form) goes with it. These two parts (the selection and the form) are inside a container. I made the width of the container the width of the selection box so you can drag it so that the form goes out of the picture, but the selection must stay inside the image.

The problem with this is that when you resize the image, not only does the form not keep to the right side of the selection, but you can then drag part of the selection outside of the image (because it's still referring to original size)

What would be the best way to achieve the functionality of this that I want to? I just want to be able to allow the user to drag around the tag and make it any size, as long as it stays inside the image. The form part should be able to go anywhere, as long as it's always attached to the right.

Here's the jQuery I currently use for dragging and resizing:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#cap_selec_container").draggable({
   containment : "#center_frame"
 });
 $("#caption_selection").resizable({
   containment : "#center_frame"
 });
});
```

Please, if you have any idea how to solve this, help me!

Comment: in Chrome, I am facing weird issues, while moving.
and Unexpected token ) at 394

Comment: Holy crap! I have no clue why that is happening. It doesn't do anything like that in FF. I'll have to ask a question about it later...

Comment: where can I resize the image?